# Как посмотреть автора строк SVN в PhpSorm

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm

Есть видел в NetBeans такая фича по работе из SVN - показываются прямо в редакторе автора строк, чтобы увидеть кто что писал в PhpStorm нужно поставить плагин, нажать историю, нажать на номер конкретного коммита - просмотреть какие изменения вносились в этом коммите.
Есть ли похожая штука в PhpStorm? (видеть автора строк)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно этот режим называется "blame" то есть поиск крайнего за сломаный код :)

В Php Storm эта штуковина спрятана под названием "annotate". Правый клац по файлу, Git > Annotate. Слева появится столбик с авторами, датами и комитами.

[правка] А, лол, вам SVN нужен. Ну там тоже этот annotate есть. Только не помню где. Нет на чем проверить :)

Comment: VCS | Subversion | Annotate

Comment: также можно делать так: контекстное меню на файле -> Subversion -> Annotate

Comment: спасибо помогли разобратся